# Align icon the right middle of the button

Tags: html, css

I have created the button with text and icon (chevron >) but cannot align it to vertically to locate it to the right of the text and  in the middle. Now I got this:

[image]

And then I tried `vertical-align: baseline;` or `vertical-align: middle;` but no reaction.

I know it is super simple but I am a fresher here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    .Background {
      width: 195px;
      height: 52px;
      padding: 12px 8px 12px 16px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: #007f00;
    }

    span {
      width: 115px;
      height: 28px;
      margin: 0 29px 0 0;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-stretch: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: 1.75;
      letter-spacing: normal;
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .Right-Small-16 {
      width: 27px;
      height: 27px;
      margin: 1px 0 0 29px;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="Background">
    <span>Reset password</span>
    <img src="images/right-small-16.svg" class="Right-Small-16" height="16px">
  </button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Apply display:flex; on button css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the size of the button and add `display: flex;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    .Background {
      width: 195px;
      height: 52px;
      padding: 12px 8px 12px 16px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: #007f00;
      display: flex;
      width: 250px;
    }

    span {
      width: 115px;
      height: 28px;
      margin: 0 29px 0 0;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-stretch: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: 1.75;
      letter-spacing: normal;
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .Right-Small-16 {
      width: 27px;
      height: 27px;
      margin: 1px 0 0 29px;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="Background">
    <span>Reset password</span>
    <img src="images/right-small-16.svg" class="Right-Small-16" height="16px">
  </button>

</body>

</html>
```